# A question on divisors of $A=(q^n-1)(q^n-q)(q^n-q^2)\cdots(q^n-q^{n-1})$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $A=(q^n-1)(q^n-q)(q^n-q^2)\cdots(q^n-q^{n-1}),$ where $q=p^r,\ p$ is prime and for some $r\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}.$ Does $q^s,$ for some positive integer $s,$ divide $A?$

Or what are the divisors of $A?$

How to proceed to find them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, $q$ divies $A$?

Comment: Note that $A$ is the order of the general linear group $GL_n(F)$, where $F$ is a finite field of order $q$. Thus, the orders of the subgroups of $GL_n(F)$ are all divisors of $A$ (Lagrange's Theorem).

Comment: Of course, thank you, i'm intending to find  the order of 3-sylow subgroup of $GL_4(F),$ where $F$ is the field having 3 elements.

Comment: So  i need to find the largest $r$ such that $3^r$ divides $A=(3^4-1)(3^4-3)(3^4-3^2)(3^4-3^3),$ isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(q^n-q^k\right)=q\cdot q^2\cdot\ldots\cdot q^{n-1}(q^n-1)(q^{n-1}-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(q-1)=$$

$$=q^{\frac{(n-1)n}2}(q^n-1)(q^{n-1}-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(q-1)$$

Comment: thanks, so $q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ divides $A.$ Is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ the largest power of $q$ which divides $A?$

Comment: @math_maniac Yes, since $\forall l\in\mathbb N\cap [1,n](\gcd(q^l-1, q)=1)$.